# assign a path to a file, in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following code, which works in SAS Studio:

```
DATA test;
INFILE "/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/test.csv"
    DLM=","
    FIRSTOBS=2;
INPUT ID V1 V2;
RUN;
```

The task is to assign the path earlier to an object and use it later, something similar to:

```
%LET myfile="/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/test.csv";
DATA test;
INFILE myfile
    DLM=","
    FIRSTOBS=2;
INPUT ID V1 V2;
RUN;
```

However, this generates an error in SAS "No logical assign for filename MYFILE"

Is there any possibility to achieve this?
I have only a very basic SAS understanding, and I was told that SAS requires setting a LIBNAME first, but I have no idea how to combine the LIBNAME (essentially the working folder) with the file name "test.csv" that I need to import.

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use one of the following two forms:

```
%LET myfile="/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/test.csv";
DATA test;
    INFILE &myfile.;
```

or

```
FILENAME myfile "/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/test.csv";
DATA test;
    INFILE myfile;
```